# Child record re-numbering per parent record

Tags: sql-server

I have a parent and child table like the following:

```
 Parent Table

 CourseId  |  CourseName
 1         |  MVC training
```

and the

```
Child Table

Id  | StudentId  | CourseId  | AttnDate 
1   | 33         | 1         | 6/1/2019
2   | 33         | 1         | 6/2/2019
3   | 33         | 1         | 6/3/2019
4   | 34         | 1         | 6/1/2019
5   | 34         | 1         | 6/2/2019
6   | 34         | 1         | 6/3/2019
```

I searched over google to use rownumber to make this but could not make it.

No idea

I want the final result like the following table. What I need is to change the 33 to 1 and 34 to 2:

```
Id  | StudentId  | CourseId  | AttnDate 
1   | 1         | 1         | 6/1/2019
2   | 1         | 1         | 6/2/2019
3   | 1         | 1         | 6/3/2019
4   | 2         | 1         | 6/1/2019
5   | 2         | 1         | 6/2/2019
6   | 2         | 1         | 6/3/2019
```

Comment: Why can't you just subtract 32 from StudentId...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using  DENSE_RANK()

```
    SELECT Id, 
         DENSE_RANK()OVER( ORDER BY StudentId) AS StudentId,
         CourseId,
         AttnDate
    FROM Parent p 
    INNER JOIN Child c  ON c.CourseId = p.CourseId
    ORDER bY  p.ID
```

Comment: Thank you but I need the number per courseId to start from 1 but currently it ranks for all the available records

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to "change the 33 to 1 and 34 to 2"? Is it for the purpose of assigning unique rank number for each distinct row within the partition (data grouped by `StudentId`)?
If it's true, then SQL Server [DENSE_RANK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) ranking function is what you need

```
SELECT *, 
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY c.StudentId) AS RowNumberRank -- here is your rank number (StudentId in your final result)
FROM  Child c
```